# Authenticate requests to server with an Apple/Google Sign-in verified client

Tags: android, ios, authentication, client-server

I have the following situation:
I have an app that will be using a subscription based payment system via the app or play store. I want to avoid implementing my own account system and verify the users via the Apple-ID or what the equivalent is on Android side, using Apple/Google Sign-in if this is possible.

The problem is that the app will have to communicate with a server every week, so that means the requests to the server need to be authenticated, that this is coming from a client (smartphone/tablet) that has an active subscription going. How do i do this the best way?

If i understand correctly then using Apple Sign-in you will get a token. Should i send this token to the server, where the server then communicates with the App Store API to verify the token on every request? Is this completely equivalent on the Android/Play store side? Or should i verify the token once on the first request, then generate my own token and send it to the client so for the rest of the session it can authenticate using that token to avoid having to go to a third party system on every call. But how do i store this self-generated token? As it needs to be linked to something on the client. Am i legally allowed to store Apple-IDs on a server?